# Twisted deferred not callable after connection failure

Tags: python, twisted, factory, deferred

Having my client factory here:

```
import logging, traceback
from twisted.internet.protocol import ClientFactory
from twisted.internet import defer, reactor, ssl
from twisted.application import service
from protocols.smpp.protocol import SMPPClientProtocol

class SMPPClientFactory(ClientFactory):

    protocol = SMPPClientProtocol

    def __init__(self, config):
        self.config = config

    def getConfig(self):
        return self.config

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print "clientConnectionFailed"

        self.connectDeferred.errback(reason)

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print "clientConnectionLost"

    def connect(self):
        self.connectDeferred = defer.Deferred()
        factory = SMPPClientFactory(self.config, self.msgHandler)

        self.log.warning('Establishing TCP connection to %s:%d' % (self.config.host, self.config.port))
        reactor.connectTCP(self.config.host, self.config.port, factory)

        return self.connectDeferred
```

And it's launching code here:

```
import logging, traceback
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from protocols.smpp.configs import SMPPClientConfig
from protocols.smpp.smpp_operations import SMPPOperationFactory
from testbed.client import SMPPClientFactory

class SMPP(object):

    def __init__(self, config=None):
        if config is None:
            config = SMPPClientConfig()

        self.config = config
        self.opFactory = SMPPOperationFactory(config)

    def run(self):
        try:
            #Bind
            SMPPClientFactory(self.config, self.handleMsg).connect().addErrback(self.connectFailed)
        except Exception, e:
            print "ERROR: %s" % str(e)

    def connectFailed(self, reason):
        print "Connection failed %s" % str(reason)

    def handleMsg(self, smpp, pdu):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = SMPPClientConfig(host='127.0.0.1', port=2775, username='smppclient1', password='password',
                              log_level=logging.DEBUG)

    logging.basicConfig(level=config.log_level, filename=config.log_file, format=config.log_format,datefmt=config.log_dateformat)
    SMPP(config).run()
    reactor.run()
```

When the connection is failing (the remote server is down), i get factory's clientConnectionFailed called but it is strangely getting a "exceptions.AttributeError: SMPPClientFactory instance has no attribute 'connectDeferred'".

I need to call the errback when the connection fails, it seems there's something missing when dealing with deferreds ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your launch code, you instantiated an SMPPClientFactory and called connect() on it. This particular instance will have the connectDeferred attribute. However, connect also instantiated another SMPPClientFactory: `factory = SMPPClientFactory(self.config, self.msgHandler)` and this is the instance you used to create the actual connection. This doesn't have the connectDeferred attribute because with this instance connect has never been called.